# HTTP "Proxy" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, http

Is there an API to perform HTTP Receive operation in Javascript like how HTTP Send can be done using`XMLhttpRequest`?

(I don't want to use node.js because the platform on which I'd like to do HTTP Receive does not support node.js).

Here's the exact problem statement :

I've to write "HTTP Proxy" on a Smart-TV Platform (whose programming environment is HTML5 & JavaScript). This proxy listens on 'localhost', receives the HTTP requests from the Smart-TV Player, adds a proprietary HTTP header to the received HTTP request, sends this modified request to a server & relays the server response back to the Smart-TV Player.

So, I'd like to implement "HTTP Server" & "HTTP Client" as a part of this HTTP Proxy. I know how to implement "HTTP Client" portion (using `XMLhttpRequest`), but I'm not sure about "HTTP Server" portion.

We can't install any package like node.js on this SmartTV environment..

Comment: Look up Server Push for the tech you wish to use.

Comment: What is "HTTP Recieve" ?

Comment: If you don't want to use Node.JS to run your JS … what do you want to use? It doesn't do much good to tell us that the most common tool to do what you want isn't supported if you don't tell us what is. You don't even tell us what platform you are using.

Comment: What's wrong with using `XMLHttpRequest` and GET rather than `XMLHttpRequest` and POST? You do realize that `XMLHttpRequest` can both request _and_ send data, right?

Comment: Here's the exact problem statement : I've to write "HTTP Proxy" on a Smart-TV Platform. This proxy listens on 'localhost', receives the HTTP requests from the Smart-TV Player, adds a proprietary HTTP header to the received HTTP request, sends this modified request to a server & relays the server response back to the Smart-TV Player. So, I'd like to implement "HTTP Server" & "HTTP Client" as a part of this HTTP Proxy. I know how to implement "HTTP Client" portion, but I don't know how to implement "HTTP Server" portion. We can't install any package like node.js on this SmartTV environment.

Comment: What server-side platforms ( languages / frameworks) are you allowed to use in your smart-tv host targets?

Comment: You need to be more specific than "SmartTV". The host environment will provide a bunch of APIs. That might include an API for running an HTTP server (although I wouldn't think it likely) but without knowing the platform, we can't tell what APIs it provides (because we don't know what documentation to consult).

Comment: @DimitrisZorbas : This platform supports HTML5/JS/CSS as programming environment

Comment: @Quentin : This is 'Samsung Smart TV' platform. As per their API documentation, there's no API support for HTTP Server or provision to run node.js. There is however 'Native Client' support (NaCl) which supports "Pepper API" which provides "TCP socket" level functions (https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/pepper_stable/c/struct_p_p_b___t_c_p_socket__1__1)  using which one can potentially build an HTTP Server. However, I'm not sure if this support is available for pre-2014 devices. That's why I was looking at any generic JS based HTTP server implementation (if it's possible).